# What is the optimal way (not using Scalaz) to type require a non-empty List?

Tags: list, scala

As I am working a design model, I am torn between two different methods of indicating a parameter of type `List` must be `nonEmpty`. I began by using `List[Int]` with an accompanying `require` statement to verify the `List` is `nonEmpty`.

```
case class A(name: String, favoriteNumbers: List[Int]) {
  require(favoriteNumbers.nonEmpty, "favoriteNumbers must not be empty")
}
```

I then needed to make the list optional. If the `List` is provided, it must be `nonEmpty`. I'm using using `Option[List[Int]]` with an accompanying `require` statement to verify, if the `Option` is `nonEmpty`, the list must also be `nonEmpty`.

```
case class B(name: String, favoriteNumbers: Option[List[Int]]) {
  require(
      favoriteNumbers.isEmpty || favoriateNumbers.get.nonEmpty
    , "when defined, favoriteNumbers.get must be nonEmpty"
  )
}
```

However, I need to use this non-empty `List` all over the system I am modeling. This means that my code has these same `require` statements duplicated everywhere. Is there a (non-ScalaZ) way to have a new type, say `NeList`, which is defined and behaves identically to List, with the only change being an exception is thrown when `NeList` attempts to be instantiated with no elements?

I tried to Google for this and couldn't find a set of search terms to hone on this area. I either got really simple `List` how-tos, or all sorts of references to ScalaZ's NEL (Non Empty List). So, if there is a link out there that would help with this, I would love to see it.

Comment: It's not super elegant, but the `case class A(name: String, h: Int, t: List[Int]) { def favoriteNumbers = h :: t }` approach works pretty well if Scalaz (or rolling your own equivalent) isn't an option.

Comment: While it is an interesting variation, it seems it still requires I create duplicate code everywhere. IOW, you've just replaced the requires statement with a 'def favoriteNumbers = ..." method.

Comment: why isn't scalaz's NEL an option? It sounds like exactly what you want.

Comment: Requiring a head makes it impossible to construct an invalid instance, though—you're not just replacing the `requires`, you're replacing the need for any kind of runtime check.

Comment: Can you clarify whether you want compile-time safety or just less-boilerplate-y runtime checks?

Comment: @TravisBrown It was three things. I need to communicate with the user that it must be nonEmpty, I want compile time safety checks. And I want to avoid all the extra boilerplate every time I decide to use the type. Additionally, I want to extend the pattern to Strings. The answer greggory.hz provided enables all of these.

Comment: This isn't what you _should_ want.  You should want compile-time safety.  If you don't have it, you should accept boilerplate to avoid undetectable runtime failures.  (Unless the code isn't doing anything important.)

Comment: @RexKerr Given my comment (just prior to yours), I don't understand what I shouldn't want. The second of my three things I wrote I wanted was "compile time safety checks". How is that different from what you are saying? Or are you indicating that the other two benefits are ones I shouldn't want?

Comment: @chaotic3quilibrium my answer doesn't provide compile time type safety. That is to say, you can't pass arbitrary arguments into the function. However, you can pass an empty list into the function and that will cause a *runtime* error. To gain compile-time safety in this sense, you'd have to drop the implicit def list2Nel and requite users to guarantee that the list is empty before they pass it in.

Comment: @greggory.hz I get it...now after reading through all of this several times and then finally figuring out Rex Kerr's answer. I added a comment to his answer about trying to use a typedef to change it from ::[A] to something readable; i.e. text, not an operator.

Comment: @chaotic3quilibrium first time I've talked someone out of my answer :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you

```
def foo[A](x: ::[A]) = "List has length "+x.length
```

then you insist that the list be nonempty.  But of course your lists are all typed as `List`, so you need a helper method to give you a nonempty list:

```
implicit class NonEmptyList[A](private val underlying: List[A]) {
  def ifNonEmpty[B](f: ::[A] => B): Option[B] = {
    underlying match {
      case x: ::[A @unchecked] => Some(f(x))
      case _ => None
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can safely apply the operation to get an `Option` out.  (You could also run side-effecting functions in a foreach-like method.)

Now, this is rather non-idiomatic Scala.  But it is safe at compile time (the `@unchecked` notwithstanding--Scala's compiler isn't quite smart enough to realize that the type parameter hasn't changed).

Comment: What do you mean by "non-idiomatic":?  Is there a problem using `::` as a nonempty list (either stand alone or together with a normal `List` and the implicit conversion)?

Comment: @Beryllium - It's not intended for use this way.  As an example, `map` on `::` will return not a `::` but a `List` even though `map` doesn't change the number of elements.

Comment: While my answer was accepted, I still believe this is the better approach. I've done something similar previously, but instead of :: I used scalaz.NonEmptyList. This solves the problem mentioned with ::.map. NonEmptyList.map always returns a NonEmptyList. And the conversion to a normal List is simple as well.

Comment: Okay. I am good with this being the better approach which is actually type checked safe. However, than it is quite cryptic, especially for non-Scala readers; i.e. Java developers. This Scala model is being shared with non-Scala API users. So, is there a way to alias a name to :: so I can use NonEmptyList[A] instead of ::[A]? IOW, can I "typedef NonEmptyList = ::"?

Comment: @chaotic3quilibrium The syntax is `type NonEmptyList = ::`.

Comment: @RexKerr Regarding the non-idiomatic comment: I would only be using this to communicate a precondition at the API level on public input parameters only; case class constructors, public methods, etc.. Everywhere else, I would expect to see and use and expect my clients to see and use List.

Comment: This can be `extends AnyVal` to get boiled down to the underlying `List[A]` at runtime, right?

Comment: @Yawar - Yes, it can be made a value class.

Answer (score 6):

You could implement a non-empty list yourself with implicit conversions between List[A] and Nel[A]:

```
case class Nel[A](val head: A, val tail: List[A] = Nil)

implicit def list2Nel[A](list: List[A]): Nel[A] = {
  require(!list.isEmpty)
  Nel(list.head, list.tail)
}

implicit def nel2List[A](nel: Nel[A]): List[A] = nel.head :: nel.tail
```

Then you can define your functions where this is needed such that they take a Nel[A] as a parameter:

```
def f(l: Option[Nel[String]]) = { ... }
```

And call them with normal lists (assuming the implicit defs are in scope):

```
f(Some(List("hello", "world")) // works
f(Some(Nil)) // throws IllegalArgumentException
f(None) // works
```

EDIT: It should be noted that this does not provide compile time guarantees that the List[A] passed in will not be empty. If that's what you want, then get rid of the `implicit def list2Nel` and require clients of your function to pass in an Nel[A] explicitly, thus guaranteeing at compile time that the list is not empty.

Also, this is a very basic NonEmptyList implementation. A more complete solution is found in scalaz (granted it was specifically requested in the question that scalaz not be used): https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.2.x/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/NonEmptyList.scala

Comment: An implicit conversion that fails with an exception at runtime under completely unexceptional conditions is pretty scary.

Comment: If a list being non-empty is an invariant and `require ` serves as an assert statement, there is IMHO no problem with the exception.

Comment: @MarcelKrcah - Because the whole point of creating a non-empty list is to put the invariant in the type instead of asserting it at runtime.

Comment: This is close enough to what I am seeking; the placing of the nonEmpty-ness into the type for the two main benefits: A) explicitly communicating to the API client the parameter must be a nonEmpty list, and B) to avoid depending upon a run-time check which I must remember to paste with each use of the class. And it appears I can apply this same pattern to String as well.

Comment: @Lee - I understand, but IMHO there are cases when it's not possible to encode the non-empty invariant into a type without throwing an exception. For example: you query the db and you know that the result must be a non-empty list. How would you code this? Personally, I solve this by creating a simple `case class NonEmptyList[A](x:List[A]) { require(x.nonEmpty)}` and wrap the db result in this type. Possibly with implicits to avoid boilerplate.

Comment: @MarcelKrcah - Converting a `List[A]` to a `NonEmptyList[A]` is a partial operation so encode that in the conversion by returning an `Option\Either\Try[NonEmptyList[A]]` instead.

Comment: While I stand by my answer to chaotic's question (it answers what was asked), in general, my feeling is that if you need a NonEmptyList, you should use a NonEmptyList and have the type system enforce it. I'm with @Lee in regards to returning an `Option/Either/Try` in cases where you might not get back a list that isn't empty or simple an Option[Nel] in cases where you want no list or a non-empty list as a parameter.

Comment: @Lee: Usage of `Option/Either/Try` vs. `require` imho depends on the input data. If you _expect_ invalid data (user form inputs, payloads of API requests, etc), use `Option/Either/Try`. However, if input _must_ always be a non-empty list, capture this with a `require` and throw an exception, so you get alerted that there is something wrong with your code.

Comment: @MarcelKrcah the main trouble with require is that you don't know something is wrong with the code until you run it. In the case of a NonEmptyList being required, you're saying runtime errors are better than compile time errors. Given the option, I will always pick compile time errors. If input must always be a non-empty list, encode that in the types used.